# Join the same table temporary table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, temp-tables

I like to join a temporary table in MySQL which fails, the idea quite simple:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table LIKE any_other_table; -- srsly it does not matter which table

(
  SELECT p1,p2,p3 FROM temp_table WHERE p4 = 1
) UNION (
  SELECT p1,p2,p3 FROM temp_table WHERE p4 = 2
)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The error thrown by mysql is  `ERROR 1137 (HY000): Can't reopen table: 'temp_table'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query.

Please read the following link 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Comment: Thanks for your information. Unfortunately this is needed for the more complex case.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
SELECT p1, p2, p3
FROM temp_table
WHERE p4 in (1, 2);
```

It is a much simpler way to write the same query.

EDIT:

If by "fail" you mean "doesn't return any rows", then you have a simple problem.  `CREATE TABLE LIKE` does not populate the table.  It creates a table with the same structure as `any_other_table`, but with no rows.  You should then populate it with `insert`.  Or, use `create table` with the `select` statement only.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  Just make sure your new table has a different name then the existing one.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_table

SELECT p1,p2,p3 FROM existing_table WHERE p4 = 1

UNION 

SELECT p1,p2,p3 FROM existing_table WHERE p4 = 2
;
```

Comment: how can you select from a table that doesn't exist yet ?

Comment: I edited to change the new table name.  I'm assuming the select query is running against a table that exists.

Answer (score 1):

Creating copies of the temporary table seems to work and may be a viable alternative approach:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 LIKE temp_table;
INSERT INTO t2 SELECT * FROM temp_table;

(
  SELECT p1,p2,p3 FROM temp_table WHERE p4 = 1
) UNION (
  SELECT p1,p2,p3 FROM t2 WHERE p4 = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
I solved by creating a temporary from the temporary table previously computed:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempo2 SELECT * FROM tempo;
```

And then applying my logics