# Is it possible to read data from TEMPTABLE and Write it to another TEMPTABLE?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I need to know is it possible to read the date from the **temptable** and again insert that data to the another **temptable** using stored procedure in MySQL

I want to read the data from one temp table and again insert that data into the another temp table by whatever order I wish to insert is it possible?

> temptable1(read)   -------->  temptable2(write)

Thanks in advance

This is my stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure search(
                                in search_key varchar(255)
                            ) 
BEGIN 

    -- Drop the temp table if already exist

    DROP temporary table IF EXISTS temptable; 

    -- Creating temp table 

    create temporary table temptable( 

        SELECT    member .member_type

              FROM       member member 
              LEFT JOIN org_person orgPerson 
              ON         orgPerson.person_id = member .id 
              INNER JOIN organization organization 
              ON         organization.id = orgPerson.org_id  
              ORDER BY   organization.name);

    -- Drop the temp table if already exist

    DROP temporary table IF EXISTS temptableSearch;

    -- Creating another temp table

    create temporary table temptableSearch like temptable;

    -- Inserting value from table

     insert into temptableSearch 
                  select *
                  from   temptable temp
                  where  temp.name like 'search_key' 

            UNION

                  select *
                  from   temptable temp
                  where  temp.name like 'search_key%' 

            UNION

                  select * 
                  from   temptable  temp 
                  where  temp.name like '%search_key%'; 

    select DISTINCT * 
  from            temptableSearch;

  END // 
  DELIMITER ;
```

When I am calling this it shows the following error

```
Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table: 'temp'
```

and I found one thing that error happen because of this part only

```
insert into temptableAffiliationSearch 
                      select *
                      from   temptableAffiliation temp
                      where  temp.name like 'search_key' 

                UNION

                      select *
                      from   temptableAffiliation temp
                      where  temp.name like 'search_key%' 

                UNION

                      select * 
                      from   temptableAffiliation temp 
                      where  temp.name like '%search_key%';
```

Comment: Why would that not be possible? You should try the first idea that pops into your head, it will probably work. (If not, you should post that code here). Just the point "by whatever order I wish" is not entirely precise, because rows in a table do not have an order. They get an order when you read them (e.g. `select * from table order by somecolumn`). But you could use an auto_increment column in your new table and order by that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18831014/3340665

Comment: Its show the same error again

Comment: can you please rewrite my code If you don't mind

Comment: Why union the same table 3 times when you could just query it once with the correct where condition?

Comment: I had changed that to single insert and the problem is resolved

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: I need to use that table for relevant search that's why I had use that Union 3 times for the same table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

As I said previously the error is in this part

```
        insert into temptableSearch 
                  select *
                  from   temptable temp
                  where  temp.name like 'search_key' 

            UNION

                  select *
                  from   temptable temp
                  where  temp.name like 'search_key%' 

            UNION

                  select * 
                  from   temptable temp 
                  where  temp.name like '%search_key%';
```

> **We cannot able to access the temp table more than once in the same query**

So I rewrite the query as

```
   insert into temptableSearch 
                  select *
                  from   temptable temp
                  where  temp.name like 'search_key' ;

   insert into temptableSearch 

                  select *
                  from   temptable temp
                  where  temp.name like 'search_key%' ;

   insert into temptableSearch 

                  select * 
                  from   temptable temp 
                  where  temp.name like '%search_key%';
```

Now It's working fine.